# NSURLConnection not logging to the console

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to get XML from a page, but the `NSURLConnection` is not returning anything.

```
- (void)downloadDataWithMission:(NSString *)mission
{    
    // Create a new data container for the stuff that comes back from the service
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // Construct a URL that will ask the service for what you want
    NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/"];

    // , mission, [self getCountry]

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];

    // Put that URL into an NSURLRequest
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Create a connection that will exchange this request for data from the URL
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

# pragma mark NSURLConnection

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere
    [xmlData setLength:0];
}


// This method will be called several times as the data arrives

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Add the incoming chunk of data to the container we are keeping
    // The data always come in the correct order
    [xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // We are just checking to make sure we are getting the XML
    NSString *xmlCheck = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"xmlCheck = %@", xmlCheck);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection object, we're done with it
    urlConnection = nil;

    // Release the xmlData object, we're done with it
    xmlData = nil;

    // Grab the description of the error object passed to us
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection Failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];

    // Create and show an alreat view with this error displayed
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [av show];
}

@end
```

Why is the connection not working? Is this a problem in the delegate? In another project, all worked fine. The base SDK was the same in those projects - iOS 6.1.

Comment: Is that the actual code you're testing? Did you breakpoint / log each method? Are any called?

Comment: this is the actual code. the code only works in `- (void)downloadDataWithMission:(NSString *)mission` method.

Comment: Device / simulator? How have you defined `urlConnection` (strong property)?

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the problem. I runned the NSURLConnection from background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything up to this line works perfectly:

```
NSString *xmlCheck = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However it does not handle the encoding I think. Maybe there is sone invalid UTF-8 char at google. Try NSASCIIStringEncoding instead and it will work. If you want to use UTF-8 you might need to dig into why google is not UTF-8 compliant.

Comment: `NSLog` not working even in `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` method.

Comment: Works for me, you should know that there is a bug in some xcode versions that might require you to restart both xcode and the computer before you see any logs again. That is if logging is not working. In your code you have no NSLog in didReceiveData. I added it to your code and on my computer it works fine.